# How to add react custom element in angular 6

Tags: angular, reactjs, angular6, custom-element, angular-elements

I have created a react application and defined it as custom element. 
customElements.define('react-iis', ReactElement);
i have built this application and got js files
i use this element directly inside normal html file it works fine
but how can i call this element from angular component/html?

in Basic html, i imported react js files i got after build and used the `<react-iis></react-iis>` it works

```
<html>
<body>
<react-iis></react-iis>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../reactelementsbuild/build/static/js/2.8490447d.chunk.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../reactelementsbuild/build/static/js/main.1cd38f24.chunk.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../reactelementsbuild/build/static/js/runtime~main.a8a9905a.js"></script>
</body>
<html>
```

Can anyone help to do the same from angular component

Comment: check this link https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular you will have to import your `.js` files in `angular.json`. (You might even merge those files into one, and then you only have to import one instead of three)

```
"scripts": [
  "src/assets/react-component/2.8490447d.chunk.js",
  "src/assets/react-component/main.1cd38f24.chunk.js",
  "src/assets/react-component/runtime~main.a8a9905a.js"
]
```

After that you will have to let Angular know that you will be using non angular elements / elements unknown to your application - [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA](https://angular.io/api/core/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA)

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  ....
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Now you are ready to use your react custom element same way as you used it in your React app - by using `<react-iis></react-iis>`